# Proving that the iterated limit and the two dimensional limit are same

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

If $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (a,b)} f(x,y) = L$ and if the one dimensional limits : $\lim_{x \rightarrow a}f(x,y)$ and $\lim_{y \rightarrow b}f(x,y)$ both exist, prove that :

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow a} [~\lim_{y \rightarrow b} f(x,y)] =  \lim_{y \rightarrow b} ~[~\lim_{x \rightarrow a }f(x,y)~]$$

**Attempt:**

$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (a,b)} f(x,y) = L$ means limit exists from any direction, whether we take a curved path first along $x=a$ and then come up to $y=b$. Or, we move along $y=b$ and then come upto $x=a$. Hence, we should be able to infer that $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} [~\lim_{y \rightarrow b} f(x,y)] =  \lim_{y \rightarrow b} ~[~\lim_{x \rightarrow a }f(x,y)~]$.

However, I wanted to write down a more rigorous proof. Here's how I started off :

$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (a,b)} f(x,y) = L$ means, $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists ~\delta $ neighborhood such that $|f(x,y) - l|<\epsilon$ whenever $(x,y) \in \delta$ neighborhood.

$\implies l-\epsilon<f(x,y) <l +\epsilon$ whenever $(x,y) \in \delta$ neighborhood.

Could anyone please tell me how do I proceed from here?

Thank you very much for your help in this regard.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since $\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y) \to (a,b)} f(x,y) =l$, for every $\epsilon >0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that if $|x-a| < \delta$ and $|y-b| < \delta$ then

$$|f(x,y) - l| < \epsilon.$$

Let

$$l_a(y) = \lim_{x \to a} f(x,y).$$

Then with $|y-b| < \delta$,

$$|f(x,y) - l| < \epsilon \implies \lim_{x \to a} |f(x,y) - l| \leqslant \epsilon \implies |l_a(y) - l| \leqslant \epsilon.$$

Note that $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a} |f(x,y) - l| = |l_a(y) - l|$ follows from $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to a}f(x,y)= l_a(y)$ and the reverse triangle inequality

$$||f(x,y) - l| - |l_a(y) - l|| \leqslant |f(x,y)-l_a(y)|.$$

Hence, if $|y - b| < \delta$ then $|l_a(y) - l| \leqslant \epsilon$ and we can conclude that

$$\lim_{y \to b} [\lim_{x \to a} f(x,y)] = l.$$

Now repeat the argument switching $x$ and $y$ to conclude that

$$\lim_{x \to a} [\lim_{y \to b} f(x,y)] = l.$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please clarify  how it's concluded from here that $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} [~\lim_{y \rightarrow b} f(x,y)] =  \lim_{y \rightarrow b} ~[~\lim_{x \rightarrow a }f(x,y)~]$?

Comment: @Wanderer: The above argument shows that $\lim_{y \rightarrow b} ~[~\lim_{x \rightarrow a }f(x,y)~]=l$.  Then you can repeat the argument, switching $x$ and $y$, and show  $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} ~[~\lim_{y \rightarrow b }f(x,y)~]=l$

Comment: So, we proved that $|l_a(y) - l| \leqslant \epsilon$.  Do we now take the $\lim_{y \rightarrow b}$ on both sides to prove that  $\lim_{y→b} [ lim_{x→a}f(x,y) ]=l$?

Comment: I added to the answer.  We showed that with $y$ in the $\delta$ neighborhood, $|l_a(y) - l| \leqslant \epsilon$ holds -- so we have already shown that the first iterated limit is $l$.

Comment: @Wanderer: You're welcome.

Comment: @RRL can you please clarify me why do we need the reverse triangle inequality? Up to the linee of that line I understood the proof but from then on I didn't understand how it proves that the iterated limit equals $l$. (My problem is that it seems to me that we need the smaller sign in the other way, but I'm probably wrong), Thanks!

Comment: @Mickey:  I just inserted that part to justify switching the limit and the absolute value in $\lim_{x \to a} |f(x,y) - l| = |\lim_{x \to a} f(x,y) - l| = |l_a(y) - l|$. You might take this for granted, but to be thorough it requires justification. Since $\lim_{x \to a} f(x,y) = l_a(y)$ for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta > 0$ such that if $|x - a| < \delta$ then $|f(x,y) - l_a(y)| < \epsilon$.  Now we use the inequality to get $| \, |f(x,y) - l| - |l_a(y) - l| \, | \leqslant |f(x,y) - l_a(y)| < \epsilon$ proving we can switch the limit and the absolute value.

Comment: Now that you know $|\lim_{x \to a} f(x,y) - l| = |l_a(y) - l| < \epsilon$ when $|y-b| < \delta$ we have that $\lim_{y \to b} (\, \lim_{x \to a}f(x,y) \, ) = l$

Comment: @RRL , great! thanks, I know see that the reverse traingle inequality looks just like the limit definition. So just to make sure - we conclude that $|f(x,y)-l_a(y)|<\varepsilon$ from the definition of the double limit and thus getting $|l_a(y)-l|<\varepsilon$?

Comment: @Mickey: Not quite.  I'm proving the part $\lim_{y \to b}(\, \lim_{x \to a}  f(x,y) \,) = l$ given that the double limit $l$ exists and the inner limit $l_a(y) = \lim_{x \to a} f(x,y)$ exists.  In my comment I use that $|f(x,y) - l_a(y)| < \epsilon$ when $x $ is close to $a$ just in explaining the triangle argument. I should have used a different symbol like $|x - a| < \hat{\delta}$. I already used $\delta$ for the double limit condition $|f(x,y) - l| < \epsilon$ when $|x - a| < \delta$ and $|y-b| < \delta$ in the first statement of the proof.

Comment: @RRL, yeah, but I meant that your final conclusion - that $|l_a(y)-l|<\varepsilon$ from the fact that for every neighborhood $\delta$ of $b$, $|f(l_a,y)-l|<\varepsilon$ because of the definition of the double limit?