# Problem in finding $\delta$ to prove that $\lim_{x\to a}[\lim_{y\to b}f(x,y)]=\lim_{y\to b}[\lim_{x\to a}f(x,y)]=L$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

**Theorem: Let $f$ be a vector field. If $\lim_{(x,y)\to(a,b)}f(x,y)=L$ and $1$D limits $\lim_{x\to a}f(x,y)$ and $\lim_{y\to b}f(x,y)$ exist then, $\lim_{x\to a}[\lim_{y\to b}f(x,y)]=\lim_{y\to b}[\lim_{x\to a}f(x,y)]=L$**.

I tried to prove it **as follows:**

Geometrically, let $\lim_{x\to a}f(x,y)=g(y)$, whence it follows that we fix some $y$ arbitrarily and then approach $a$ along $x$-axis to get $\lim_{x\to a}f(x,y)$. Similarly for the other $1$D limit.  Then since the limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to(a,b)}f(x,y)=L$ exists, it doesn't matter how we approach $(a,b)$ and hence the result is verified.**Is my interpretation correct?**

**Now coming to the proof:** Let $\lim_{y\to b}f(x,y)=h(x)$. Since $\lim_{(x,y)\to(a,b)}f(x,y)=L$, it follows that $\forall \epsilon_1 \gt 0, \exists \delta_1 \gt 0$ such that if $0\lt \sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}\lt \delta_1$, then $||f(x,y)-L||\lt \epsilon_1 \tag{1}$ 
Since $\lim_{x\to a}f(x,y)=g(y)$, it follows that $\forall \epsilon _2\gt 0, \exists \delta_2\gt 0$ such that if $0\lt |x-a|\lt \delta_2$, then $||f(x,y)-g(y)||\lt \epsilon_2 \tag{2}$ 
Similarly, $\forall \epsilon _3\gt 0, \exists \delta_3\gt 0$ such that if $0\lt |y-b|\lt \delta_3$, then $||f(x,y)-h(x)||\lt \epsilon_3\tag {3}$ 
<s>From (2)& (3), it follows that $\require{enclose}
     \enclose{horizontalstrike}{||g(y)-h(x)||\le ||f(x,y)-g(y)||+||f(x,y)-h(x)||\lt\epsilon_2+\epsilon_3}$, whenever $\require{enclose}
     \enclose{horizontalstrike}{0\lt |y-b|\lt \delta_3}$ and $\require{enclose}
     \enclose{horizontalstrike}{0\lt |x-a|\lt \delta_2}$ 

That is by taking $\require{enclose}
     \enclose{horizontalstrike}{\epsilon_2=\epsilon_3=\epsilon/2}$, we have $\require{enclose}
     \enclose{horizontalstrike}{||g(y)-h(x)||\lt\epsilon}$, whenever $\require{enclose}
     \enclose{horizontalstrike}{0\lt \sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2} \lt  \sqrt{\delta_2^2+\delta_3^2}}$</s>  
Since  $\lim_{x\to a}[\lim_{y\to b}f(x,y)]=\lim_{x\to a}h(x)$, consider 
$||h(x)-L||\lt||h(x)-f(x,y)||+||f(x,y)-L|\lt \epsilon_3+\epsilon_1$, whenever $0\lt |y-b|\lt \delta_3$ and $0\lt \sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}\lt \delta_1$ whence by taking $\epsilon_3=\epsilon_1=\epsilon/2$, it would follow that 
$||h(x)-L||\lt \epsilon$ whenever $0\lt \sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}\lt \delta$ and similarly for $g(y)$. 
**But the problem is how to get this $\delta$ from $(1)$ and $(3)$?** 
**I tried the following here:** since $0\lt |y-b|\lt \sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}$, taking $\delta=\min\{\delta_1,\delta_3\}$ will cure the problem. **Is this correct?**

Please help. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @RRL, First of all, I would like to thank you for taking time to respond. I am just confused as $0\lt |y-b|\lt \sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}$ is true no matter what $x, y$ may be. I haven't assumed in my answer that $\delta$'s depend only upon $\epsilon $. So I guess there is no question of uniform convergence. Can you please elaborate how $\delta$' s taken by me can create problems?

Comment: @RRL, I meant those other deltas only :) Can you please explain (by giving example, if possible) how there will be trouble in those other deltas? Thanks.

Comment: You want $|h(x) - L| < \epsilon$ to hold when $|y-b| < \delta(\epsilon)$.  You can't have $\delta(\epsilon)$ also depend on $x$.

Comment: @RRL, But if I am not mistaken, $\delta_3$ doesn't depend upon $x$. I considered a circle centered at $(a, b) $ with radius $\delta_1$ and then $(y-b) $ will be on vertical diameter of the circle. So I thought taking delta as minimum of other two will work.

Comment: You wrote: Similarly, $\forall \epsilon _3\gt 0, \exists \delta_3\gt 0$ such that if $0\lt |y-b|\lt \delta_3$, then $||f(x,y)-h(x)||\lt \epsilon_3\tag {3}$. That is how $\delta_3$ appeared and in general it is different for different values of $x$.  The limit $h(x)$ is different for different values of $x$ and a different tolerance may apply.

Comment: @RRL, Yes. I have read your answer and understood that $\delta $ in general will depend upon point and epsilon both. I am still trying to understand how mine is wrong. :'(

Comment: You are trying to use the bound $|h(x) - L| \leqslant |h(x) - f(x,y)| + |f(x,y) - L|$.  It is a true bound but how can it help you prove that the LHS is small for any $x$ only given that $|x-a|$ is smaller than a constant that depends only on $\epsilon$.  To make the second RHS term small you need both $|x-a| < \delta_1/\sqrt{2}$ and $|y-b| < \delta_1/\sqrt{2}$.  That's fine -- the LHS does not know about $y$.  How do you make the first RHS term small.  For any $x$ there is potentially a different $\delta_3(x)$ where we need $|y-b| < \delta_3(x)$ to make the first RHS term small.

Comment: How do you go from there to getting the constant that bounds $|x-a|$ to make the LHS small?   Answer -- approach it differently as I did below.

Comment: Notice how you use the triangle inequality but I am using the reverse triangle inequality and everything falls into place.

Comment: Does your definition of "vector field" imply that $f$ is continuous? The theorem is not valid if we do not assume that $\lim_{y\to b}f(x,y)$ and $\lim_{x\to a}f(x,y)$ exist for all $(x,y)$ in some nbhd of $(a,b).$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet, No, there is no implication of continuity of $f$. $f$ is defined in some deleted nbd of $(a, b) $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $|f(x,y) - L| < \epsilon_1$ when  $\sqrt{(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2} < \delta_1$.  If $|x-a| < \delta_1/\sqrt{2}$ and $|y-b| < \delta_1/\sqrt{2}$, then $\sqrt{(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2} < \delta_1$  holds and it is again true that $|f(x,y) - L| < \epsilon_1$

**It also is enough that $|x-a| < \delta_1/\sqrt{2}$ for $|h(x) - L| \leqslant \epsilon_1$ to hold as well.**

To prove this claim, note that by the reverse triangle inequality

$$||f(x,y) -L| - |h(x) - L|| \leqslant |f(x,y) - h(x)|$$

Since $h(x) = \lim_{y \to b} f(x,y)$, for any $\epsilon > 0$ and each fixed $x$ there exists $\delta(\epsilon,x) > 0$ such that if $|y-b| < \delta(\epsilon,x)$, then

$$||f(x,y) -L| - |h(x) - L|| \leqslant|f(x,y) - h(x)| < \epsilon$$

Assume that for some fixed $x$ where $|x-a| < \delta_1/\sqrt(2)$ we have  $|h(x) - L| > \epsilon_1$.

Take $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}(|h(x) - L| -\epsilon_1)$ and $|y-b| < \min(\delta(\epsilon,x), \delta_1/\sqrt{2})$.  It follows that

$$|f(x,y) -L| - |h(x) -L| > - \epsilon = -\frac{|h(x) - L|}{2}+ \frac{\epsilon_1}{2},$$

implying

$$|f(x,y) -L| > \frac{|h(x) - L|}{2}+ \frac{\epsilon_1}{2} > \epsilon_1$$

This contradicts $|f(x,y) - L| < \epsilon_1$ and we can conclude that $|h(x) - L| \leqslant \epsilon_1$, Therefore,

$$\lim_{x \to a} \lim_{y\to b} f(x,y) = \lim_{x \to a}h(x) = L$$

---

The proof that $\lim_{y \to b} \lim_{x\to a} f(x,y) = L$ is handled in the same way.

A shorter proof is to simply say that $|h(x) - L| = \lim_{y \to b}|f(x,y) - L|$ and $|f(x,y) - L| < \epsilon_1$ implies that $|h(x) - L| \leqslant \epsilon_1$.  These steps are justified by well-known limit theorems which are embedded in the proof above.

Comment: +1. Thanks a lot.  I have understood except the shorter proof part.

Comment: Thanks a lot again. I referred to your other answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1129239/266435. It alongwith this answer, solves my doubt.

Comment: @Koro: You’re very welcome. The short proof just uses the facts  that (1) limit commutes with absolute value and (2) if $f(x) < C$ them $\lim_x f(x) \leqslant C$.